# CSS multi-column layout of forms in Firefox

Tags: forms, css, firefox, webkit, multiple-columns

It looks like FireFox (my version is 19.0.2 - OSX) doesn't render forms properly using multicolumn layout.  It renders normal paragraph text etc properly, but not forms.

**The CSS:**

```
fieldset {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

**This is what it looks like in FireFox:**
[image: CSS Multicolumn rendering of form fieldset in FireFox- doesn't render columns]

**This is what it looks like in WebKit browsers:**
[image: CSS Multicolumn rendering of form fieldset in WebKit browsers - renders columns properly]

Please view this [sample code / live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prembo/3NWFp/) in FireFox to see that it doesn't render the multi-column layout for form elements.

Is this a bug, or is there something I can do to get it working in FireFox too?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the multi column attribute can't apply for the moment on this specific markup element that you use (namely fieldset). 
Fieldset is dedicated to group some form fields, but I'm not sure it is already implemented to render in multi column...
So I should think that it is a bug that will be corrected in the future...

You can counter this by creating a simple div with flot left for the first form elements... Of course, with this option, you have to manually split the form elements that will be drawned on the left and on the right, you don't have the magic of equals length mutli-colmun anymore...

```
div#column1{
  width : 400px;
  float : left;
}
div#column2 {
 float : left;
}

<div id="#column1">Your first fields</div>
<div id="#column2">Your second fields</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this option Stéphane - unfortunately, unable to change markup. I think we may just have to live with the Firefox's rendering.